# This version of Visual Studio does not have the following project types installed

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

I try to open solution in VS v2012+ and get the error

```
Unsupported This version of Visual Studio does not have the following project types 
installed or does not support them. You can still open these projects in the version of 
Visual Studio in which they were originally created.
 - SetupDoktersAdministratie, "C:\Users\sta_it\Desktop\Jonas\Dokadmin\backup
\SetupDoktersAdministratie\SetupDoktersAdministratie\SetupDoktersAdministratie.vdproj"


No changes required These projects can be opened in this version of Visual Studio without 
changing them. They will continue to open in Visual Studio 2010 SP1 and in this version of 
Visual Studio.
- SetupDoktersAdministratie, "C:\Users\sta_it\Desktop\Jonas\Dokadmin\backup 
\SetupDoktersAdministratie\SetupDoktersAdministratie.sln"
```

Will this say i'm only able to open these files in vb2010?

Comment: Look, these setup projects were discontinued after 2010. So, you need to use something else for distribution

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudio/archive/2014/04/17/visual-studio-installer-projects-extension.aspx